# How to pull new docker images to openshift cluster nodes from remote private registry?

Tags: docker, openshift, kubernetes, docker-registry, openshift-origin

All steps specified in https://blog.openshift.com/remotely-push-pull-container-images-openshift/ (and other sources) worked perfectly on master, but it does not help me to pull from nodes.

Details:

1. Logged in on master and two nodes to registry: **docker login
   https://my.registry:5000**
2. Created new secret on master with: **oc secrets new my.registry
   .dockerconfigjson=/root/.docker/config.json** (can't do the same on
   nodes, because they do not have oc utility)
3. In my current project added secret for default account: **oc secrets
   add serviceaccount/default secrets/my.registry --for=pull**

Now when I'm naking a new deployment, the pods created on master will start perfectly well (master will be able to pull needed images), but pods on nodes will fail to start unless I manually pull images on them with docker pull.

So how can I make all nodes from my openshift (origin) cluster pull images with specified default account?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the command may have changed somewhat with recent versions of origin. The following works for me:

```
oc new-project my-project
oc secrets new docker-pull-secret .dockerconfigjson=${HOME}/.docker/config.json --namespace=my-project
oc secrets link default docker-pull-secret --for=pull --namespace=my-project
```

Comment: This does not differ from my steps. I did not specify namespace, and did not link to it, but I am already making these steps when my current project is "my-project". So I still can see with **oc get/describe sa** that secrets where added, but it does not help my nodes to pull images.    And you are saying that your nodes does not get such errors?

Comment: Correct it pulls to all nodes as expected

Comment: Thank you for response! So basicaly - if you add a secret for pull to project's default builder account - this will be enough for all nodes to pull images? There is no need to do any additional steps on them - am I right?

Comment: That should work, what registry are you trying to pull from? Maybe check your Docker config on master node and compare it with your other nodes, you may be missing the insecure registry from `/etc/docker/daemon.json`

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in https://github.com/openshift/origin/issues/13122
Master somehow managed to pull and extract images faster, while nodes had a timeout.